# Generate Solution File From List of CSProj

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've got alot of projects and I don't have a master solution with everything in it.  The reason I want one is for refactoring.

So I was wondering if anybody knew an automatic way to build a solution file.  Manually adding all the projects just isn't feasible.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that some of your projects may reference compiled dlls instead of the projects that created those dlls. When that is the case, VisualStudio's built in refactorings will not cross that boundry. So if a utility method signature is changed, an app that references the utility dll instead of the project won't be automatically changed to match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And I have now updated my utility (mentioned above) to support creation of solution folders:
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2009/12/03/utility-to-generate-solution-files-can-now-create-solution-folders.aspx

Comment: Can you provide the code for that? That way others can extend it (for example: if they have vbproj files or something.)

Comment: The source code is available at BitBucket:
https://bitbucket.org/object/solutionmaker/

Comment: These links are now broken.

Answer (score 20):

In 2018, you can use [`dotnet sln`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln) command to add project to an existing solution and [`dotnet new sln`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) to create a new one.

To add all projects from current folder use these commands in PowerShell

```
dotnet new sln
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.csproj | ForEach { dotnet sln add $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_23600576.html) (the code below comes from this site, of all sites..)

But if it doesn't work and it would take too much time to debug, I would suggest going for the pain of adding them manually once. Just put some good music and go for it... :)

@oefe I don't think VS.NET allows you to D&D projects into solutions, I've tried that once.

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Shared Sub DoStuff()

        Dim filePath As String = "c:\temp"

        Dim fileName As String = "bld_TestApp.sln"

        Dim fullName As String = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)

        Dim objType As Type

        Dim objDTE As EnvDTE.DTE

        objType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.8.0")

        objDTE = DirectCast(System.Activator.CreateInstance(objType), EnvDTE.DTE)

        Console.WriteLine(objDTE.Name + ":" + objDTE.Version)


        objDTE.Solution.Create(filePath, fileName)

        objDTE.Solution.AddFromFile("C:\Common.vbproj")

        objDTE.Solution.SaveAs(fullName)


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Vagif Abilov wrote a wonderful utility that will generate a solution file from project files. It is amazing if you are working for people who don't "believe" in solution files. ugh.

GenerateSolutionFile.exe

Usage: GenerateSolutionFile /p  /s  [/i includeFilter] [/e excludeFilter]

The blog was removed and it contained a zip with the code:
https://web.archive.org/web/20090810131702/http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2009/08/04/utility-to-generate-visual-studio-solution-file-for-a-group-of-projects.aspx

It looks like the author uploaded an msi version of this tool here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VagifAbilov.SolutionMaker

From what I can tell, the Microsoft slngen is probably the better solution, since it is MIT licensed source code and is an active project.
https://github.com/microsoft/slngen

Comment: This link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in 2017, Microsoft build another tool to generate solutions: https://github.com/microsoft/slngen - this project appears to be actively maintained.

Answer (score -2):

I've programmatically using text manipulation created solution files for .vcproj files (but cs/vb would work just the same). It isn't really hard to figure out how to do it if you open up a solution file in notepad or whatever.

Unfortunately I cannot provide the code as it is proprietary.

Answer (score -3):

Create an empty solution, then drag & drop all your projects into it at once?

Comment: The original question stated that manually adding them wasn't feasible.

Answer (score -3):

Check out nAnt, the .NET port of Ant.  It has the ability to do stuff like this, or to build without it.

Comment: This is quite interesting:  I have given the best solution, yet I have been downvoted the most, and not a single comment to explain what the #$%## anyone is thinking.  Meanwhile, the worst solution (involving some funky custom code) gets upvoted.

Comment: Just guessing here, but your answer would be far more helpful if you were to provide the exact NAnt task that merges all of the projects.

Comment: From what I understand, nAnt can replace solution files, but I do not know how it can create solution files -- which I'm actually a fan of, but it may not fit everyone's needs.